# Is there any reference type in racket?

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I wanted to implement a doubly linked list in racket. At the beginning I wrote a simple two node list to test referencing in racket. Here is my code:

```lisp
#lang racket

(struct node (val next) #:transparent #:mutable)

(define n0 (node 0 null))
(define n1 (node 1 n0))
n0
n1
(set-node-next! n0 n1)
n0
n1
```

Here is the corresponding output:

```
(node 0 '())
(node 1 (node 0 '()))
#0=(node 0 (node 1 #0#))
#0=(node 1 (node 0 #0#))
```

The first and second line of the output is what I expected from the code but after that I don't have any clue about what it is doing. I guess those # are related to reference, but I couldn't find anything on the web. Can anyone explain this output for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about them being references. In Racket, pretty much all types (except for integers, and other compiler optimizations I won't go into here) refer to an object stored in a sort of heap. Because of that, when you called `set-node-next!`, you told Racket to point the structures `next` field back to the original struct. Basically forming a cycle:

[image]

The `#0=` notation is a way Racket is able to print out back references. You can read about it more in [the docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html?q=%230%3D#%28idx._%28gentag._89._%28lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl%29%29%29), but in short, when you see `#0=`, its saying that `#0#` refers to *this* structure, and therefore if you see it, that's where the back-reference (so to speak) is.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I have another question. When racket uses reference instead of whole structure when `set-node-next!` is called?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: For example if I define n0 like this `(define n0 (node 0 null))` and then 
`(set-node-next! n0 (node 1 null))`, the result will be `(node 0 (node 1 '()))`. Why exactly it didn't store the reference in n0-next?